# Using SQL Server docker container on vs2017-win2016 hosted agent

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm attempting to use Azure Pipelines to create a more streamlined CI process for `pymssql` with Windows and Linux. The Linux build is able to successfully download and start the Docker `MSSQL` image for integration test, but when I attempt to do the same thing for Windows the image never successfully downloads even with a 45 minute timeout. Has anybody successfully started the Docker `MSSQL` container on a MS Windows Hosted Agent?

https://dev.azure.com/alexander-hagerman/pymssql/_build/results?buildId=48

`azure-pipelines.yaml`

```
jobs:

- job: Windows
  timeoutInMinutes: 45
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Python37:
        python.version: '3.7'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '$(python.version)'

  - script: docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=YourStrong@Passw0rd -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer:latest
    displayName: 'Start SQL Server container service'

  - script: cp tests/tests.cfg.tpl tests/tests.cfg
    displayName: "Create config file from template for test connections."

  - script: pip install tox cython
    displayName: 'Install initial dependencies'

  - script: tox -e py
    displayName: 'Run Tox'
```

Comment: Did you try run the pipeline in your self hosted agent?

Comment: I have not, that kind of defeats the purpose of switching from something like appveyor to Azure Pipelines. It would be nice to have all my builds in one tool, but not if I have to bring my own hardware. If I’m misunderstanding the self hosted agent being on my own system let me know but that’s how I read it.